# How to access all the nested structs of a MATLAB .mat variable file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, scipy

I am trying to read a MATLAB variable file (.mat), which contains a struct, containing several structs until it reaches the lowest level, for example:

- struct1

  - struct1.member1
  - struct2.member2

    - struct2.member2.data1
    - struct2.member2.data1

The problem is that, using `scipy.io.matlab`'s `whosmat` (I'm dealing with a large file, so it wouldn't be ideal to load it all with `loadmat`), I can only access the first struct1 with output similar to:

```py
filename = /path/to/file
data = scipy.io.matlab.whosmat(filename)
display(data)
```

Output:
`['struct1', (1, 1), 'struct']`

So there is no obvious way to access the members of this struct. Any ideas?

Comment: `loadmat` lets you specify variable names, such as `struct1`.  But you'll have to accept loading the whole variable, and find you desired data within that.  `whosmat` just gives variable names.

Comment: from that `whosmat` it looks like the file has just one variable.  Use `loadmat` to load it.  The result will be an array with a complex mix of `object` dtype and structured arrays.